# linux kernel buffer memory is zero

Tags: linux-kernel, buffer

There are one qestion that i can`t find in google.

I have many linux boxes mostly with SLES or openSUSE, diffrent versions and kernels.
On some of them i faced with slow oracle transactions problem. It time to time problem and when i log in the box on that time i see that oracle blocked in kernel function sync_page

```
# while :; do ps axo stat,pid,cmd,wchan | egrep '^D|^R'; echo --; sleep 5; done
D     3483 hald-addon-storage: polling ide_do_drive_cmd
Ds    4635 ora_dbw0_orcl               sync_page
Ds    4637 ora_lgwr_orcl               sync_page
Ds    4639 ora_ckpt_orcl               sync_page
D    11210 oracleorcl (LOCAL=NO)       sync_page
D    12457 [smtpd]                     sync_page
R+   12458 ps axo stat,pid,cmd,wchan   -
--
Ds    4635 ora_dbw0_orcl               sync_page
Ds    4637 ora_lgwr_orcl               sync_page
Ds    4639 ora_ckpt_orcl               sync_page
D    11210 oracleorcl (LOCAL=NO)       sync_page
R+   12501 ps axo stat,pid,cmd,wchan   -
--
Ds    4635 ora_dbw0_orcl               sync_page
Ds    4637 ora_lgwr_orcl               sync_page
Ds    4639 ora_ckpt_orcl               sync_page
D    11210 oracleorcl (LOCAL=NO)       sync_page
R+   12535 ps axo stat,pid,cmd,wchan   -
--
Ds    4635 ora_dbw0_orcl               sync_page
Ds    4637 ora_lgwr_orcl               sync_page
Ds    4639 ora_ckpt_orcl               sync_page
D    11210 oracleorcl (LOCAL=NO)       sync_page
R+   12570 ps axo stat,pid,cmd,wchan   -
--
```

so i think that box is run out of memory for disk buffers but

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       4149084    3994552     154532          0          0    2424328
-/+ buffers/cache:    1570224    2578860
Swap:      3148700     750696    2398004
```

i think that this is the problem, buffer is zero and we must write directly to disk, but why buffer is zero - i try to google it and find nothing - is anyone can help ?

**UPD**

```
billing@Billing-server:~> uname -a
Linux Billing-server 2.6.18.2-34-bigsmp #1 SMP Mon Nov 27 11:46:27 UTC 2006 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Ask this on serverfault, not here.

Comment: `sync_page` is not a syscall. In your case, the disk limits your operating speed.

Comment: Ok i understand that disk is limit my speed. But why kernel not buffering it ?

Comment: sometimes, the disk request can't be buffered. What is your `uname -a`, how much memory is installed, and what you get from `iostat` ?

Comment: As free say we have 4Gb RAM, and pretty old kernel. No problem right now so nothing interest in iostat. But this is not low-ram swapping problem, swap never used hard.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Database uses the `O_DIRECT` flag to specifically request that the kernel **not** buffer its disk access - Oracle performs its own buffering.

Your results indicate that you're saturating your available disk bandwidth.

Comment: OK, but what about other daemons ?
logrotate with tons of logs, zabbix_proxy with its database - they not use O_DIRECT, but they write much and still - no buffer used.